# Single word/short phrase for 'discussion across ideological/political lines to understand a different point of view'?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Would there be a single word/short phrase to convey the meaning of 'discussion across ideological/political lines to understand a different point of view'

The type of conversation would be where people with different perspectives enter a conversation with the aim of **understanding (as opposed to debating)** an opposing viewpoint. A good example of an online forum would be Reddit's [r/ChangeMyView](https://www.reddit.com/r/changemyview/).

I was thinking of 'non-partisan discourse', but that would indicate that the discussion itself was based on a common grounds.

Comment: The articles you point to seem to be diatribes, seeking to impose a certain point of view.

Comment: In the US, we call that [crossing the aisle](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/cross+the+aisle) or [extending an olive branch](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/hold-out-offer-an-olive-branch).

Answer (score 1):

A good word for the said description is **parley**

> A discussion between two groups of people, especially one that is intended to end an argument

*Indeed, one or two defenders are already appearing on the battlements asking for a parley; we must not grant this.*

[Cambridge Dictionary]